# android OnSensorChanged() slow response

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I have code implemented like this:

```
    //register sensor in OnResume
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;

    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);

        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

            azimuth = (int)( Math.toDegrees( orientation[0] ) + 0.5 );    // orientation contains: azimuth, pitch and roll
            pitch = (int)( Math.toDegrees( orientation[1] ) + 0.5 );
            roll = (int)( Math.toDegrees( orientation[2] ) + 0.5 );

            // output azimuth, pitch and roll
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine in Galaxy Nexus cell, but it has problem in nexus tablet (the updating of azimuth, pitch and roll are not well responding, sometimes take 5 to 8 secs).

I have checked that the calling of OnSensorChanged() is working well, but the "if(success)" test is not always success which gets this problem.

I tested it by output the boolean variable "success":

- In Galaxy Nexus, the rate of false and true is about 1:1.
- In Nexus tablet, the rate of false and true varies a lot, can be high as >20 : 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem lies with the following code:

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

it should be:

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values.clone();
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();

Otherwise the "getRotationMatrix" method will frequently return "false". But I am not sure why?

Comment: Thank you very much.  Been scratching my head past couple of hours trying to figure out why!!!  This fixes the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the following code:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) mGravity = event.values; if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) mGeomagnetic = event.values;
```

it should be:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) mGravity = event.values.clone(); 
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();
```

Otherwise the "getRotationMatrix" method will frequently return "false". But I am not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because there is a fixed pool of SensorEvents and if you are using the data in them directly it can change out from under you, but by cloning it you can make use of that data at any time.